# Variable in event of react list component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions

Here is my code:

```
export default function App() {
  const array = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];
  let progress = "";
  const list = array.map((item) => {
    progress += `/${item}`;
    return (
      <input
        key={item}
        type="button"
        value={item}
        onClick={() => {
          console.log(progress);
        }}
      />
    );
  });
  return <div className="App">{list}</div>;
}
```

Also, you can try it on [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/variable-in-event-of-list-component-uftm3?file=/src/App.js:24-406)

When I click item1 button on the page. Why the console log `/item1/item2/item3`?

The expected behavior is that:

When item1 button is clicked. Console log `/item1`;

When item2 button is clicked. Console log `/item1/item2`;

...

Thanks.

Comment: What is the expected behavior? Do you want to show only the item you click on? or Do you want to append it every time? Either way you should move `progress += item;` to your onClick function rather than letting it run for every iteration.

Comment: No answers in the question, please. I have rolled back/edited your question and removed the answer. Add the answer in the answer section only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click the button, the arrow function you provided will fire. This means that the function will read the variable only when the arrow function is being called. And since the progress variable isn't being created inside the mapping or arrow function, but rather outside it, the last mapped input element will set it to `item1item2item3`, meaning it will be the same when you click each of the inputs.

To fix this, you could assign a local variable to be equal to progress inside the map method, like so:

```
export default function App() {
  const array = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];

  let progress = "";

  const list = array.map((item) => {
    progress += item;
    let local = progress;
    return (
      <input
        key={item}
        type="button"
        value={item}
        onClick={() => {
          console.log(local);
        }}
      />
    );
  });
  return <div className="App">{list}</div>;
}
```

I haven't tested this exactly, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

When your code is executed, the array.map method runs the callback function provided for every element of the array. So when your program finished executing, the value of **progress** will be **item1item2item3** and all you're click handlers are closing over the same variable **progress**(In closures a reference to the variable is kept) and hence the result **item1item2item3**.

You can solve this by defining a new scope for every handler using the IIFE.

````
export default function App() {
  const array = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];
  var progress = "";
  const list = array.map(function (item) {
    progress += item;
    return (
      <input
        key={item}
        type="button"
        value={item}
        onClick={(function(progress){
          return function () {
            console.log(progress);
          }
        })(progress)}
      />
    );
  });
  return <div className="App">{list}</div>;
}```
````